# Can I invoke nested functions for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, f#, functional-testing

In F# I want to perform unit testing on a function with several levels of nested functions.
I want to be able to test the nested functions individually as well, but I do not know how I could invoke them.
When debugging, each of these nested functions is invoked as a type of function object, but I don't know if I can access them at compile time.

I do not want to change the nesting scheme that I am using because it makes the most sense functionally to have them nested this way because there is a de facto "inheritance" of some of the function parameters at each nested level.

Is something like this possible?  If not, what is the general procedure for unit testing nested functions?  Are they tested individually with extra parameters and then inserted into their nested position afterwords never to be able to be tested again?

Very small example:

```
let range a b =
    let lower =  ceil a |> int
    let upper =  floor b |> int
    if lower > upper then
        Seq.empty
    else
        seq{ for i in lower..upper -> i}
```

How could I test that `lower` or `upper` are working properly without changing the nested nature of the code?

Comment: +1 Not possible, but I'm curious to see the suggested workarounds. :-]

Comment: If `range` works correctly couldn't you assume `lower` and `upper` do as well?

Comment: @Daniel, this is a simple example.  And actually, not a very good one since lower and upper don't really bind into functions.  But, what about a much more complicated example, where nested helper functions might be quite complex in themselves, and thus should be tested apart from the entire containing function.

Comment: @mattgately You may want to revisit the definition of "unit" in the term "unit test".  If the unit in question is a function then you're not testing the interior functionality--you're testing the function. I mean if you need to test lower and upper (or some analog of them) make them their own standalone unit of code.

Comment: Actually they are standalone units: `ceil` and `floor`. They are part of standard library. No need to test it on your side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would agree with Daniels comment - if the outer function works correctly, you should not need to test any of the inner functions. Inner functions are really an implementation detail that should not be relevant (especially in functional code, where output does not depend on anything else than inputs). In C#, you also don't test whether `for` loop or `while` loop inside your method works correctly.

If both the inner and the outer functions are too complex, then perhaps it would be better to write the inner function as a separate function anyway.

That said, you can, of course, mess with the compiled assembly using reflection and invoke the inner function. Inner functions are compiled as classes with constructor that takes the *closure* (captured values of the outer function) and `Invoke` method that takes the actual parameters.

The following trivial example works, though I have not tested it on anything more realistic:

```
open NUnit.Framework

// Function with 'inner' that captures the argument 'a' and takes additional 'x'    
let outer a b = 
  let inner x = x + a + 1
  (inner a) * (inner b)

// Unit tests that use reflection in a hacky way to test 'inner'
[<TestFixture>]
module Tests = 
  open System
  open System.Reflection

  // Runs the specified compiled function - assumes that 'name' of inner functions
  // is unique in the current assembly (!) and that you can correctly guess what 
  // are the variables captured by the closure (!)
  let run name closure args = 
    // Lots of unchecked assumptions all the way through...
    let typ =
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()  
      |> Seq.find (fun typ -> 
          let at = typ.Name.IndexOf('@')
          (at > 0) && (typ.Name.Substring(0, at) = name) )
    let flags = BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic
    let ctor = typ.GetConstructors(flags) |> Seq.head
    let f = ctor.Invoke(closure)
    let invoke = f.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")
    invoke.Invoke(f, args)

  /// Test that 'inner 10' returns '14' if inside outer where 'a = 3'
  [<Test>]
  let test () = 
    Assert.AreEqual(run "inner" [| box 3 |] [| box 10 |], 14)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomas.  I was wondering how this could be done with reflection.  It is, as I expected, very complex and not worth doing because of its very unfriendly syntax for executing simple inner functions. I was hoping that there would be an easier way of supplying the "closure" arguments, and that testing in this manner would be possible without modifying the program structure, which illustrates the hierarchy of the problem in the best manner.

Comment: +1 for "Inner functions are really an implementation detail that should not be relevant *(especially in functional code, where output does not depend on anything else than inputs)*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @mattgately With a bit of effort, you could make the syntax nicer. Using `?` operator, you could probably get something like `Assert.AreEqual(funcs?inner 3 10,  14)` or if you had function that takes two closure arguments and two actual arguments then something like `funcs?inner (3.14, "pi") (1, "hi")`. But I think there shouldn't be need to test inner functions anyway.

Comment: @mattgately For a related example that uses `?` in a similar way, see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304373

Comment: I accepted your answer, since the explanation and comments at least give enough reason for me to give up on what I was calling "unit testing" of nested functions.

Comment: I still would be interested if somebody had a method for doing this even if it is not strictly unit testing.  The reason is that I believe that the functional paradigm allows me to implement a program in a way that most directly represents the actual problem at hand.  Also, I believe that it makes sense that if a function is really only used in one function (and shares inputs) then there is a natural hierarchy to be used. I would rather not modify the natural structure to faciliate testing.  Perhaps somebody has a suggestion for how to fit the tests into the natural nesting hierarchy?